# How to compare a variable in list of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following list.

```
$scope.Document.push( {
        'Id': ''
        'Name': "",
        'mandatory': "false",
        'status': "1"
    },
    {
        'Id': ''
        'Name': "",
        'mandatory': "false",
        'status': "2"
    },
   {
        'Id': ''
        'Name': "",
        'mandatory': "false",
        'status': "2"
    });
```

I want to find whether in the list contains more than one object contains only I want to do some operation. How can I find that status in all objects.

```
if($scope.Document contains morethan one object status 1){
   $scope.Document[index].status = 2;

}
```

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more, probably with an example.

Comment: `if($scope.Document.filter(function(x){ return x.status == 1;}).length > 1)`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov this satisfies my requirement

Comment: @user9130953, I am glad, that your task is completed

Answer (score 0):

To check this you can use length property

```
if($scope.Document.length > 1)
{
//Do your operation
}
```

Refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp) to get more about javascript length